# Problem with SQLite executemany

Tags: python, pysqlite

I can't find my error in the following code. When it is run a type error is given for line: *cur.executemany(sql  % itr.next())*  => '**function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**,

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table IF NOT EXISTS fred (dat)")

def newSave(className, fields, objData):
    sets = []
    itr = iter(objData)
    if len(fields) == 1:
        sets.append( ':' + fields[0])
    else:
        for name in fields:
            sets.append( ':' +  name)
    if len(sets)== 1:
        colNames = sets[0]
    else:
        colNames = ', '.join(sets)
    sql = " '''insert into %s (%s) values(%%s)'''," % (className, colNames)
    print itr.next()
    cur.executemany(sql  % itr.next())
    con.commit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    newSave('fred', ['dat'], [{'dat':1}, {'dat':2}, { 'dat':3}, {'dat':4}])
```

I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Seeing this title drive me crazy. Title should summerize the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Like it says, executemany takes two arguments. Instead of interpolating the string values yourself with the %, you should pass both the sql and the values and let the db adapter quote them.

```
sql = " '''insert into %s (%s) values(%%s)'''," % (className, colNames)
cur.executemany(sql, itr.next())
```

Comment: that's right, except interpolation in sql uses the ? character, not %, so the original sql string should be "insert into %s (%s) values (?)" % (className, colNames)

Answer (score 2):

See [the sqlite3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany). As you'll see, the `Cursor.executemany` method expects two parameters. Perhaps you mistook it for the `Connection.executemany` method which only takes one?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers. After pushing and poking for several days and using your guidance the following works. I'm guilty of overthinking my problem. Didn't need an iter() conversion. The objData variable is a list and already an iterable! This was one of the reasons the code didn't work.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table IF NOT EXISTS fred (dat, tad)")

def newSave(className, fields, objData):
    colSets = []
    valSets = []
    If len(fields) == 1:
        colSets.append( fields[0])
        valSets.append(':' + fields[0])
    else:
        for name in fields:
            colSets.append( name)
            valSets.append(':' + name)
    if len(colSets)== 1:
        colNames = colSets[0]
        vals = valSets[0]
    else:
        colNames = ', '.join(colSets)
        vals = ', '.join(valSets)
    sql = "insert into %s (%s) values(%s)" % (className, colNames, vals)
    cur.executemany(sql , objDat)
    con.commit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    newSave('fred', ['dat',  'tad'], [{'dat':  100, 'tad' :  42}, {'dat': 200 , 'tad' : 43}, {'dat': 3 , 'tad' :  44}, {'dat': 4 , 'tad' :  45} ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant:

> cur.executemany(sql, itr)

also note that the print statement consumes one item from the iterator.